# convert twitter created_at into hour minute time in r

Tags: r, api, twitter, lubridate

I want to convert the created_at column from Twitters API into hours and minutes.

I tried:

```
budlight_tweets<-budlight_tweets %>% 
  mutate(hm(tweet_time = substr(created_at, 12,16)))
```

my logic was that the I cut everything off the created_at other than the hour and minute portion and then I thought hm would convert the snipped portion to an hour minute format.

Comment: Your logic is OK but you mixed up the order of function and variable in `mutate`. Try `mutate(tweet_time = hm(substr(created_at, 12,16)))`.

Comment: There might be different ways to get `created_at` from the API, and some people who could help with the conversion might not be familiar with it. It would be helpful in your question to show example data, ideally by including the output of `dput(head(budlight_tweets))` so we can easily reproduce a sample of your data in the same format that you have it.